# Regular expression: if three letters are included

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got a number of word:
`hello, poison, world, search, echo ...`
And I've got some letters `e, h, o`
Now I need to find all words that includes this letters. Like `search, echo` for `e, h, o`

I can search this way:

```
words = %w[hello poison world search echo]
matched = words.select do |w|
  %w[e,h,o].all?{ |l| w =~ /#{l}/ }
end
```

The problem is that if letters are `o, o, o`, or `l, b, l` this search will return true for words like `open` or `boil`, but I need to search words that includes three of `o` or two of `l` and one `b`

**upd:**

```
leters = "abc"
words.select{ |w| w.count(letters) >= 3 }
```

**upd 2**

Bad solution, example:

```
"lllllll".count("lua") #=> 5
```

Comment: How many words? If you want good performance across an entire dictionary, the solutions will be different.

Comment: How large is your text? And will you need to run several 3-letter-sets against it?

Comment: about 500-1000 words (it is array, acctually). And I will run several sets (20-30 each time)

Comment: Problem is to find all words from Array that mathes to my letters sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want a regexp? Strings support counting values in them, you could use that feature. Something like this:

```
words = ["pool", "tool", "troll", "lot"]
letters = "olo"

#find how many of each letter we need
counts = {}
letters.each { |v| counts[v] = letters.count(v) }

#See if a given work matches all the counts
# accumulated above
res = words.select do |w|
  counts.keys.inject(true) do |match, letter| 
      match && (w.count(letter) == counts[letter])
  end
end
```

Comment: why can't we just use `words.select{|w| w.count(letters)}`

Comment: Got it. I like this way. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best not to use regular expressions for this, but it can be done:

All three letters different:

```
/^(?=.*a)(?=.*b).*c/
```

Two the same and one different:

```
/^(?=.*a.*a).*b/
```

All three the same:

```
/^.*a.*a.*a/
```

Comment: @floor: Count the frequency of each letter in your target three letters, and then for each letter check that it occurs at least that number of times in the word you are testing.

Answer (score 1):

Consider modifying the word (so that it becomes smaller with each check).

```
words = %w(fooo for find o ooo)
matched = words.select do |orig|
  # note: str.gsub! returns nil if nothing was replaced
  w = orig.clone
  %w(o o o).all?{ |l| w.gsub!(/^(.*)(#{l})(.*)$/, '\1\3') }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks crazy, but it works:

```
leters = "abc"
words.select{ |w| w.count(letters) >= 3 }
```

But it isn't work with cyrillic letters :(

Comment: Generalized: `words.select {|w| w.count(letters) >= letters.size}`

Comment: one serious problem: `"lllll".count(alo) #=> 5` :(

Comment: Cyrillic letters fixed with `jcount`